# How to sort bean object in SpringBoot framework?

Tags: spring-boot, sorting

I can't use the `sort()` method in a service class as below (service class) and it shows error like "asking me to create collection class in 'util' package"

Service class:

```
@Service
public class StudentManagement { 

    public List<Student> display() {
        ArrayList<Student> l=new ArrayList<Student>();
        l.add(new Student(10,"John"));//convert string object to Student 
        l.add(new Student(20,"Smith"));
        l.add(new Student(5,"Beck"));
        l.add(new Student(15 ,"Joe"));
        Collections.sort(l);  
        return l;
    }
}
```

here is a controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value="/hello")
public List<Student> show() { 
    return s.display();
}
```

Comment: Show us your Student class.

Answer (score 0):

I would use java stream api (you need java 8 +) with

```
return l.stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::name)) // name or whatever you want to sort
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```